# How to show variations only which are in stock on shop page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I don't want to show all attributes that are available, I just need to show those variations value which have stock saved on back-end.
Just like I have a variable named sizes, so i want to show the product as well as its available sizes, if a product has 5 different sizes, but two of its sizes has no stock then display only the other 3 sizes which are in stock, and if one product has 5 different sizes and all sizes are in stock then display all those sizes. Here is the code that I am using:

```
    echo '<div class="row m-0 justify-content-center">';
    $fabric_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_sizes');
    foreach ( $fabric_values as $fabric_value ) {
        echo '<button class="btn btn-circle btn-lg rounded-circle">'."$fabric_value->name" . '</button>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Here is the snap: [image: See the image here]
This shows all the attributes which I have stored before.
What's the solution, if anybody can help me?

Comment: If the first product has all these 5 sizes, but size 6 and 7 has no stock available, then size 6 & 7 should not be displayed under available sizes on shop page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved the solution:

```php
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy    = 'pa_sizes'; // The product attribute taxonomy
        $sizes_array = []; // Initializing

        // Loop through available variation Ids for the variable product
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); // Get the WC_Product_Variation object

            if( $variation->is_purchasable() && $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
                $term_name = $variation->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
                $file_list[$term_name] = $term_name;

            }
        }

        /*
         * Loop through the array and print all the values
         */
        if(is_array($file_list)){
            sort ($file_list);
            foreach($file_list as $file){ 
                echo '<button class="btn btn-circle btn-lg rounded-circle">' . $file . '</button>';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo '<p style="font-size:12px;">No Sizes Available</p>';
        }

    }

    echo '</div>';
Anyone can get help from this post if having troubles.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from stackoverflow, this works but the all the sizes are being shown in a single button, I want to show all sizes in separate buttons, like the above screenshot has.
I know its possible by adding a loop before echoing my button, my loop is not working

```
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy    = 'pa_sizes'; // The product attribute taxonomy
        $sizes_array = []; // Initializing

        // Loop through available variation Ids for the variable product
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id ); // Get the WC_Product_Variation object

            if( $variation->is_purchasable() && $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
                $term_name = $variation->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
                $sizes_array[$term_name] = $term_name;
            }
        }

        echo '<button class="btn btn-circle btn-lg rounded-circle">' . implode( ', ', $sizes_array ) . '</button>';
    }
```

So, can anybody add a loop just before echoing the button so that I can display all available sizes in different buttons.